# Turning off a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm building a website which has tooltips to give advice on what to do which display after a few seconds of inactivity. The thing is, there's certain circumstances when I don't want them to show up.

The website has 'pop-ups' (just div tags on which the z-index is changed). When these tags are 'in view' I don't want the tool tips. Is there anything I can do to the code to check if a div is at a certain level, or perhaps insert a command to NOT run the tooltip code...

My tooltip script is

```
<!-- JavaScript function to show/hide prompts after innactivity-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  var interval = 1;
setInterval(function(){
   if(interval == 9){
       $("div.container_prompts_timeout").show(); 
       interval = 1; 
   }
   interval = interval+1;
    console.log(interval);
},1000);

$(document).bind('mousemove keypress', function() {
    $("div.container_prompts_timeout").hide();
    interval = 1; 
});
 });
</script>
```

And the code I use to change z-index is:

```
<!--Code to change z-index of background divs-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeZIndex(i,id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=i;
}
</script>
```

Many thanks

Comment: jquery ui has a zindex() function which returns the zindex for an element. You could use that to get the zindex and have logic to decide whether or not to show the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use display property of your divs to hide and show them.
And you can check the state of it.
Something like

```
var my_div = getElementById("my_div");// or use your jQuery if you wish

function show() {
    my_div.style.display = "block";
}

function hide() {
    my_div.style.display = "none";
}

function is_shown() {
    if (my_div.style.display == "none") return 0;
    return 1; // use booleans if you wish, I prefer old school :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could:

- check if the popups are "visible" before showing the tooltips, or
- cancel the interval when they become visible and restart it when they are hidden

personally, I wouldn't use the z-index to show or hide things.  I would set their actual display style property to 'none' to hide them.  this would allow you to check this property before showing the tooltips, because checking the z-index of the element might be a little cumbersome.